# What's the term for design ala "object.method1().method2().method3()"?

Tags: c++

What's the term for this design?

```
object.method1().method2().method3()
```

..when all methods return *this?

I found the term for this a while ago, but lost it meanwhile.
I have no clue how to search for this on google :)
Also if anyone can think of a better title for the question, feel free to change it.

Thanks

**Update-Gishu**: After reading about it, I feel that your question is misleading w.r.t. code snippet provided.. (Feel free to rollback)

*Method Chaining*

```
object.method1().method2().method3()
```

*Fluent Interfaces*

```
private void makeFluent(Customer customer) {
        customer.newOrder()
                .with(6, "TAL")
                .with(5, "HPK").skippable()
                .with(3, "LGV")
                .priorityRush();
    }
```

Comment: Gishu, instead of replying inline like this you should leave a comment or add another answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts#14608

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks to me like you are describing a fluent interface. Ive also heard it referred to as pipelineing or chaining.

Update-Gishu: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html

Comment: "Fluent Interface" is wrong... that's a particular approach to concise, readable, flowing specification of calls through successive invocations against the return value of the previous member function, but each member function need not return a reference to `*this`: it could be some other class entirely.  Fluent programming uses method chaining as one technique, but either can exist without the other.

Comment: @TonyD Given that this is the accepted answer, perhaps the question was poorly phrased and the OP was actually referring to the programming of APIs that are used much like this. This is pretty typical of APIs referred to as "fluent".

Comment: @jpmc26: that's possible - and fluent interfaces are worthy of mention as a particular use case of method chaining (alongside the named parameter idiom) - but doesn't help future visitors to this question... the answer should address the question actually asked.  That's particularly important as other questions have been closed as duplicates of this one, so it's not just the OP here with an interest in having a sound answer.

Answer (score 10):

> It chains these method calls, which is why this is called [method chaining](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#method-chaining)

Answer (score 8):

It's usually called method chaining. An example of its application is the [Named Parameter Idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.18).

As an aside, I find it amusing that searching in Google for "object method1 method2" comes up with exactly the page you were looking for. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's called [Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). As an example, there's a boost library that provided a chaining way of assigning into a container before brace-initialization came around ([Boost.Assignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html)):

```
vector<int> v; 
v += 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;

typedef pair< string,string > str_pair;
deque<str_pair> deq;
push_front( deq )( "foo", "bar")( "boo", "far" );
```

Typically though, you see it more in other languages to do things like providing a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface):

```
 FluentGlutApp(argc, argv)
     .withDoubleBuffer().withRGBA().withAlpha().withDepth()
     .at(200, 200).across(500, 500)
     .named("My OpenGL/GLUT App")
     .create();
```

I don't see it that much in C++ personally, outside of streaming.

Answer (score 2):

chaining is a more common name in the industry and most developers have at least heard of it, while fluent interface is more academic and lots of people will have no idea what your talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is [method chaining](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#method-chaining).